# Application to download files from URL

Tags: c#, windows, email, download

[Email Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5AZw.png)

So I currently work for an engineering company and we receive files via Aconex (Aconex is a web based document management system for all consulting teams on a given project). Currently we have a system where we download the files (there is a link in the email that leads to the Aconex website) from the email and file them in a dated folder under the specific project. I've attached an image of the Aconex email link.

Now for the issue. Sometimes it can be quite overwhelming when you receive 20+ project related emails in a day (on top of everything else) and some of these may slip through the gaps.

Basically I would like to automate this process somehow. I want the user to be able to add the email link to the application, hit 'Process' and the files are then downloaded and filed under the specific project.

I've got some basic programming experience (mainly in c#) and would like to use this as my first 'real world' programming project.

Any help that can be offered is really appreciated.

Thanks people!

Comment: If indeed you are looking for *any* help, then I would offer the following: Learn how to program, and come back when you have a specific, answerable problem. This site is for developers that already know how to write code. It's not the place to ask for help learning to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually you want to make HTTP request to download it from publicly available web server?

You would need these two in the header:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
```

The IO will help you messing with the local file system paths, directories and etc. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

The Net namespace contains many options for creating requests or downloading files.

Then in a method you create a WebRequest instance, with e.g. Create static method that have an URI object as input:

```
var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlObject);
```

// here you setup your stuff like authorization or request method etc:

```
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
httpRequest.Timeout = settings.timeout;

// and finally call the request (this is an async approach)
httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(getResponse, this);
```

Here you get the response

```
public void getResponse(IAsyncResult __result)
{
   WebResponse response = httpRequest.EndGetResponse(__result);

   // here you deal with the response

}
```

Or you may use simpler way:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
Uri urlObject = new Uri("http://yourUrl");
String localPath = "local\\filesystem\\path.file";
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(urlObject, localPath, this);
```

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8bysebz(v=vs.110).aspx

Have I got your issue right?